# Set Time Zone Information

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to set time zone information using C in my Windows device.

Below is the code I have tried. I am able to **get** time zone information. When trying to **set** time zone information my code runs without error. However, when I check time zone information in Control Panel -> date / time it says:

> Your current time zone is not recognised. Please select a valid time zone.

Please help where I am doing wrong:

```
#define UNICODE 1
#define _UNICODE 1

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main()
{
   TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tziOld, tziNew, tziTest;
   DWORD dwRet;

   // Enable the required privilege

   HANDLE hToken;
   TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

   OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
   LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);
   tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
   tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
   AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

   // Retrieve the current time zone information

   dwRet = GetTimeZoneInformation(&tziOld);

   if(dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD || dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_UNKNOWN)    
   {
      wprintf(L"%s\n", tziOld.StandardName);
      wprintf(L"%s\n", tziOld.DaylightName);
   }
   else if( dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT )
      wprintf(L"%s\n", tziOld.DaylightName);
   else
   {
      printf("GTZI failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return 0;
   }

   // Adjust the time zone information

   ZeroMemory(&tziNew, sizeof(tziNew));
   tziNew.Bias = tziOld.Bias + 60;
   StringCchCopy(tziNew.StandardName, 32, L"India Standard Time");
   tziNew.StandardDate.wMonth = 10;
   tziNew.StandardDate.wDayOfWeek = 0;
   tziNew.StandardDate.wDay = 5;
   tziNew.StandardDate.wHour = 2;

   StringCchCopy(tziNew.DaylightName, 32, L"India Summer Time");
   tziNew.DaylightDate.wMonth = 4;
   tziNew.DaylightDate.wDayOfWeek = 0;
   tziNew.DaylightDate.wDay = 1;
   tziNew.DaylightDate.wHour = 2;
   tziNew.DaylightBias = -60;

   if( !SetTimeZoneInformation( &tziNew ) ) 
   {
      printf("STZI failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return 0;
   }

   // Retrieve and display the newly set time zone information

   dwRet = GetTimeZoneInformation(&tziTest);

   if(dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD || dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_UNKNOWN)    
      wprintf(L"%s\n", tziTest.StandardName);
   else if( dwRet == TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT )
      wprintf(L"%s\n", tziTest.DaylightName);
   else printf("GTZI failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

   // Disable the privilege

   tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0; 
   AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 0); 

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: So replacing India Standard Time in Day light Name...Still the same line exists Your current time zone is not recognised. Please select a valid time zone

Comment: On my Windows 7 desktop PC the time zone setting in Control Panel does not have the option "India Standard Time" however it does have "Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi". Nor does it have "GMT" or "Greenwich Mean Time" but it does have "Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London".

Comment: GMT is now called UTC (Universal Time Coordinated).

Comment: In my code what to change to make it work

Comment: @ParthDesai obviously, you need to set `tziNew.StandardName` and `tziNew.DaylightName` to names that Windows recognizes. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481.aspx), known time zones are stored in the Registry. Find the one that matches the timezone settings you want, then you'll know which name to use

Comment: Timezones are a fixed set of data in your local time conversion routine, you have to check the documentation of your system to select the proper identifier for your locale.  Probably the one used `"India Standard Time"` is not the valid one.  I'm not expert in windows configuration, so I cannot devise an answer for you.